# IndexedDB Error on Firefox with big Database (Maybe a quota?)

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I condensed my code down to the following script to show the error:

```
    const request = indexedDB.open("myDatabase",10);
request.onupgradeneeded = function myUpgradeHandlerFunction(event){ 
    //Needed for Update
    let db = event.target.result;           
    // Erstelle ein ObjectStore für diese Datenbank
    try{
        let objectStore = db.createObjectStore("PanelStore", { keyPath: ["panelkey","layerkey","countrycode"] });
    }catch(e){console.log("Indexed DB upgrade failed with:"+e);}
}

request.onsuccess = function(event){ 
    oConn=request.result; 
    let pStx = oConn.transaction('PanelStore', 'readonly');
        let panelStore = pStx.objectStore('PanelStore');
        let vcount = panelStore.count();
        vcount.onsuccess = function() {
            console.log(vcount.result);
        }
        const getall = panelStore.getAll();
        getall.onsuccess = () => console.log(getall.result);
        getall.onerror = () => console.log(getall.error);
}   
request.onerror = () => console.log(request.error);
request.onblocked = () => console.log('blocked');
```

When I do this on with "Database 1", the output is in Chrome and Firefox

```
5
Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

When I do this with "Database 2", the output is in Chrome is

```
642
(642) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
```

in Firefox it is

```
639
DOMException: The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other error code.
```

Of course the small and the big DB are created with the same script, uploaded to a webserver and downloaded (again: same script used in both browsers for both databases).

As you see the count delivered different information on Chrome and Firefox. I assume the sheer size makes a difference.

Adding some debug code in the function that populates the Indexeddb by loading the files from the server, I can see, that in Firefox 638 files upload fine, then the error "Uncaught DOMException: The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other error code." occurs (at store.put).

Maybe I'm hitting a limit within Firefox? I can't find any reliable documentation. Everyting that talks about limits is more than 8 years old and for outdated Firefox versions.

All files that are supposed to be read sum up to 274.6 MB

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Try with a cursor instead of `getAll`

Comment: I'll try that asap, but if the problem is only the getAll, then the count of entries should be the same in FF and Chrome. So I assume the problem is in the populating...